# pyspark reading file with both json and non-json columns

Tags: json, csv, pyspark, flatten

I'm trying to read and transform a csv file with both json and non-json columns.
I managed to read the file and put it in a dataframe. The schema is like this:

```
root
 |-- 'id': string (nullable = true)
 |-- 'score': string (nullable = true)
```

And if I do `df.take(2)`, I get these results:

`[Row('id'=u"'AF03DCAB-EE3F-493A-ACD9-4B98F548E6F3'", 'score'=u"{'topSpeed':15.00000,'averageSpeed':5.00000,'harshBraking':0,'harshAcceleration':0,'driverRating':null,'idlingScore':70,'speedingScore':70,'brakingScore':70,'accelerationScore':70,'totalEcoScore':70    }"),
     Row('id'=u"'1938A2B9-5EF2-413C-A7A3-C5F324FD4089'", 'score'=u"{'topSpeed':106.00000,'averageSpeed':71.00000,'harshBraking':0,'harshAcceleration':0,'driverRating':9,'idlingScore':76,'speedingScore':87,'brakingScore':86,'accelerationScore':82,'totalEcoScore':83    }")]`

The `id` column is a "normal" column and the `score` column contains data in a json format.
I want to break up the json content into seperate columns, but also need the id column with the rest of the data.
A have a working piece of code for the score column only:

```
df = rawdata.select("'score'")
df1 = df.rdd  # Convert to rdd
df2 = df1.flatMap(lambda x: x)  # Flatten rows
dfJsonScore = sqlContext.read.json(df2)
dfJsonScore.printSchema()
dfJsonScore.take(3)
```

This gives me this:

```
root
 |-- accelerationScore: long (nullable = true)
 |-- averageSpeed: double (nullable = true)
 |-- brakingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |-- driverRating: long (nullable = true)
 |-- harshAcceleration: long (nullable = true)
 |-- harshBraking: long (nullable = true)
 |-- idlingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |-- speedingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |-- topSpeed: double (nullable = true)
 |-- totalEcoScore: long (nullable = true)

[Row(accelerationScore=70, averageSpeed=5.0, brakingScore=70, driverRating=None, harshAcceleration=0, harshBraking=0, idlingScore=70, speedingScore=70, topSpeed=15.0, totalEcoScore=70),
 Row(accelerationScore=82, averageSpeed=71.0, brakingScore=86, driverRating=9, harshAcceleration=0, harshBraking=0, idlingScore=76, speedingScore=87, topSpeed=106.0, totalEcoScore=83),
 Row(accelerationScore=81, averageSpeed=74.0, brakingScore=85, driverRating=9, harshAcceleration=0, harshBraking=0, idlingScore=75, speedingScore=87, topSpeed=102.0, totalEcoScore=82)]
```

But I can't get it to work in combination with the id column.

Answer (score 4):

There is a brand new `from_json` function [added in pyspark 2.1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) that can handle your case.

Having dataframe with the following schema:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)
```

first generate schema for json field:

```
>>> score_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.score)).schema
```

then use it in `from_json`:

```
>>> df.withColumn('score', from_json('score', score_schema)).printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- accelerationScore: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- averageSpeed: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- brakingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- driverRating: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- harshAcceleration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- harshBraking: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- idlingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- speedingScore: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- topSpeed: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- totalEcoScore: long (nullable = true)
```

**EDIT**

If you cannot use spark 2.1, `get_json_object` is always an option, but requires field to be valid json, i.e. to have `"` as string delimeters instead of `'`, see this example:

```
df.withColumn('score', regexp_replace('score', "'", "\"")) \
    .select(
        'id', 
        get_json_object('score', '$.accelerationScore').alias('accelerationScore'), 
        get_json_object('score', '$.topSpeed').alias('topSpeed')
    ).show()

+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
|                  id|accelerationScore|topSpeed|
+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
|AF03DCAB-EE3F-493...|               70|    15.0|
|1938A2B9-5EF2-413...|               82|   106.0|
+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately we are still on pyspark 2.0 so I will have to look for an alternative solution

Comment: Thanks for the update. This works great for the case I'm working on.